# android HTML template as resource

Tags: html, android, resources

is there any way to have an html file (i.e. an html template) be a resource in android?  I'd like to reference it in a similar way that i store strings in the res/values/strings.xml.  However, when i do this, it appears the HTML is not getting rendered correctly when i use `myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(MessageFormat
                    .format(getResources().getString(R.string.myHtmlFile), ...)`

Comment: i should note, that when I hard-code the HTML in a string, instead of using getResources() it works fine and all the HTML formatting is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place raw HTML or other format files in /res/raw or /assets directory of your project. You can access the first with [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource(int)), and the second with [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: so this works, but then i have to go thru the pain of using an input stream.  is there a simple way that you know of to just get the contents of a file into a string?  in C#, you can just say 

`String blah = new StreamReader(myInputStream).readToEnd()`

isn't there anyway to do that in android/java?

Comment: Write a static method somewhere that takes InputStream and returns a String. Wrap the stream with BufferedInputStream, and append the data to a StringBuilder until exhausted.

Comment: blech.  i hate re-inventing the wheel, i added a ref to apache.commons.io thanks though... :)